# brave-browser won't update

Tags: updates, brave

[image]I have seen the other answers to similar problem with Brave-Browser but can't get them to work - probably because I'm not very proficient - sorry.
Anyway, here is what the terminal returns:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.
Duncan

Answer (score 2):

First you need to delete expired GPG key.

```
sudo apt-key del 4FE13824E3FFC656
```

Install latest GPG Key for Brave Browser repo, after you will be able to update it.

```
curl -s https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/brave-core.asc | sudo apt-key --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/brave-browser-release.gpg add -
```

Comment: Many thanks for your suggestion - - - unfortunately it did not work --- here is what happened:   - see attached screenshot of Terminal:

Comment: I have added a screenshot of my Terminal after executing your suggestion - above, with the original post. (don't know how to attach it to this comment - sorry). You will see that the terminal return after 'sudo apt-get update' is unchanged.

Comment: Updated answer with step to remove old gpg key.

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated. I found this helpful: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/452020/gpg-warning-unsafe-ownership-on-homedir-home-user-gnupg/452025#452025 - essentially, enter the following 2 terminal scripts: 1) $ sudo gpgconf --kill dirmngr
 2) $ sudo chown -R $USER ~/.gnupg

Answer (score 0):

Managed to find a solution - used this ref: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/452020/gpg-warning-unsafe-ownership-on-homedir-home-user-gnupg/452025#452025 - author: Stephen Kitt

In summary:
Enter the following terminal commands:

1. $ sudo gpgconf --kill dirmngr
2. $ sudo chown -R $USER ~/.gnupg
   That did it for me.
   Simples!